# File says status 200 ok, but isn't appearing (node.js, expressjs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a video file that I would like to display to the browser as just the video. So that later, my front end can call this video.

Essentially I want to access my videos like an api, so that in my front end if I have

```
<video>
   <source ="video/randomfile.mov" type="video/mov">
</video>
```

It will render the file, here is my project structure:

```
app.js
public -> videos -> video1.mov, video2.mov, video3.mov
views -> html files
node modules
```

And here is my code:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.use("/", express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


app.get("/videos/:name",function(req,res){
    let name = req.params.name;
     res.send("<video> <source src='"+name+"' type='video/mov' height='600px' width='700px'> </video>")
})


 app.listen(port);
```

However upon entering localhost:3000/videos/video1.mov the video does not display and upon looking at the network tab it looks like it has loaded (As the status is 200 ok). I am also getting the word "error" where the  usually goes in the browser

EDIT:

upon reading my network tab I realize that the type (for the video) is being read as a document

Comment: Browser's doesnt support .mov format. you need to convert the video to suitable format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.mov is not an acceptable format for use with video tag. You'll need to convert to WebM, Ogg, mp4 etc, then re-upload the asset and reference the new one with the correct format. Here is a link with acceptable formats: [HTML5 video formats](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats)